# Stopping a performSelector: from being performed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Pretty basic problem.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startSequence:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

However, is there a way to stop this after its been called? 
Thanks for any help
Disco

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`+[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3a). If there are multiple perform requests waiting, this will cancel all of them.

If you want some finer-grained control, you can use [`+[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a). Everything matching the predicate is cancelled; if you have multiple identical requests waiting, there's no mechanism to cancel a single one.

Comment: If you call `performSelector:afterDelay:` on main thread be strongly sure that you call `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` on main thread too. Otherwise it won't be cancelled!

Answer (score 11):

There sure is;

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startSequence:) object:nil];
```