# Stopping a 'performSelector afterDelay' before it fires

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I start a repeating NSTimer after a 4 second delay using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSelector:@selector(startTimer) withObject:self afterDelay:4];
}
- (void)startTimer {
    NSTimer *mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"What up!");
}
```

Problem is I may need to cancel startTimer from being called before the 4 seconds is up.  Is there a way of doing this?  I'd actually prefer to not use the performSelector in the first place (seems messy).  If only NSTimer had something along the lines of this…

> NSTimer *mytimer = [NSTimer
>   scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
>   afterDelay:4.0 target:self
>   selector:@selector(doSomething)
>   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

…then that would be perfect as I could just call the following:

> [myTimer invalidate];

Any help or tips are much appreciated =)

P.S. I've found something called cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget in the NSObject class reference.  Doesn't seem to be a method I can call from where this code runs however.  If that's getting back on the right track your feedback is welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a performSelector: from being performed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498071/stopping-a-performselector-from-being-performed)

Comment: you can use a non-repeating timer to fire off the repeating timer

Comment: Nice one Nick, a much cleaner option. Thanks! Pity I can't mark your comment as the answer. I'll have to mark the next nearest

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Plz go through the SP post link

[Stopping a performSelector: from being performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498071/stopping-a-performselector-from-being-performed)

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(sr)
                                           object:nil];
```

The documentation for -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: points you to the methods for canceling a queued perform request.

Answer (score 1):

`[myTimer invalidate]` doesn't work?
Just keep a track of the object in your class, or in a centralized store  for example.
If you do so, you could access your timer from everywhere you want, and invalidate it whenever it is needed

Comment: It does work, for a timer and now that I'm using separate timers for the start delay and repeating selectors its all good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSTimer to fix issue.

```
self.autoTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self
selector:@selector(connectionTimeout:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:autoTimer
forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and call when you want to stop timer

```
 [self.autoTimer invalidate];

 self.autoTimer = nil;
```